# My if statement is never returning true, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js

My `trueorfalse` is always returning false even if the offset to one of the numbers in the array. What should I do to fix this problem?

```
let trueorfalse;

const offsetArray=[15,30,45,60]

console.log(offset)
for(let i =0;i<4;i++){
    if(offsetArray[i]==offset){
        trueorfalse=true
    }else{
        trueorfalse=false
    }
}
```

Comment: does it return false even if offset = 60?

Comment: Use strict comparison operator `===`.

Comment: it return true at 60

Comment: still false at 30

Comment: you know you can check if a element is in a array with `offsetArray.includes(offset)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value initially to false and then if you find the offset set it to true, otherwise you are effectively checking the last element only. Code:

```
let trueorfalse = false;

const offsetArray = [15, 30, 45, 60]

console.log(offset)
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (offsetArray[i] == offset) {
    trueorfalse = true
  }
}
```